# How to return pointer to object in an array?

Tags: c++, loops, return-value, assimp

I'm using assimp to process some 3d models, and I'm iterating through child nodes from an arbitrary parent node, looking for a node with a matching string name. As the children as stored as an array, I need to return a pointer to the node at the Nth index in the array if the name matches. I have successfully found the name by matching the strings and printing them out to a FILE object(assf), however attempting to exit early by returning the pointer to the matching node, always returns 'nullptr'.

I've tried declaring a global variable to store a temporary node pointer, and copy the pointer of the matching node to the temporary pointer when a match is found. This actually *does* work, but It isn't the solution I'm looking for, especially when I feel like I have some fundamental misunderstanding of recursive functions and their return values. Or more.

```
const aiNode* fn2(const aiNode* nin, const aiString& name){
    for(unsigned int c = 0; c < nin->mNumChildren; c++){ //for every child of the node argument...
        if (nin->mChildren[c]->mName == name){ //...compare the names, and if successful enter this block
            fprintf(assf, "Found node '%s'!\n",name.C_Str());
            return nin->mChildren[c];//This IS the node i want, so why does it return null ?
        }
        else{ //The name of this node doesn't match what I'm looking for, try the next node. Repeat...
            fn2(nin->mChildren[c], name);//This WILL return the node if made called as: return fn2(nin->mChildren[c], name);
        }
    }

    fprintf(assf, "Node name (%s) not a match\n",nin->mName.C_Str());
    return nullptr;//None of the child nodes of the node passed in have a matching name!
}
```

The expected result, when the name matches, is the pointer to the current node in the array is returned and used by the calling function. The actual result is that I'm always returning a nullptr.

Edit;
Thank you Soronel and Jonathan, that makes sense and helped me come up with a working solution. By adding a temp to the function, the following code now performs as expected;

```
    for (unsigned int c = 0; c < nin->mNumChildren; c++) { //for every child of the node argument...
        const aiNode* tmpnode = nullptr; //const aiNode* tmpnode = nullptr; //Store pointer to a temp node no matter what
        if (nin->mChildren[c]->mName == name) { //...compare the names, and if successful enter this block
            fprintf(assf, "Found node '%s'!\n",name.C_Str());
            tmpnode = nin->mChildren[c]; //This IS the node i want, assign it to the temp
        }
        else { //The name of this node doesn't match what I'm looking for, try the next node. Repeat...
            tmpnode = fn2(nin->mChildren[c], name); //Call this function recursively, and store it's result in the temp
        }
        if(tmpnode) return tmpnode; //Return the matched node here, OR nullptr at end of function if no match
    }
    fprintf(assf, "Node name (%s) not a match\n",nin->mName.C_Str());
    return nullptr; //None of the child nodes of the node passed in have a matching name!
}
```

Comment: Your function is recursive, if you don't return the return value recursively too it gets lost. When you call the function recursively, save the return value and test it against nullptr. If it's non-null, return it to the higher-level caller. Otherwise, keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive call does not return the found value (if any):

```
fn2(nin->mChildren[c], name);
```

needs to be something like:

```
const aiNode* ptr = fn2(nin->mChildren[c], name);
if(ptr)
  return ptr;
```

The direct function call where the node is found is fine, it is how it is passed back up the call chain that is the problem.